# Microsoft Edge @font-face not applying when printing

Tags: css, microsoft-edge, woff, print-css

When browsing the site, all fonts are displaying properly. When printing a page, the preview and corresponding output are all in Times New Roman. Here are my CSS rules:

```
font-family: 'Metric-Regular';
src: url("fonts/MetricWeb-Regular.eot");
src: url("fonts/MetricWeb-Regular.woff") format("woff");
```

Just noticed that this is occuring. The behavior does not appear in any versions of IE, Firefox, Chrome, etc. I've been searching but haven't found anything relating to this happening when printing, only about things like Edge not supporting woff2 yet.

Here it is rendering correctly:

> [image: Rendering correctly]

Here it is in the print preview, which is also how it prints / saves as a PDF:

> [image: Printing incorrectly]

Comment: Do you have a link to an example?

Comment: Updating question with link to example.

Comment: Is there any solution/progress regarding this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you try to load these fonts inside @media print, then it is a bug in Edge that is not going to be fixed for now:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/10328179/

The solution that worked for me is to load the fonts outside the @media print decleration - like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyFont';
    src: url('../fonts/MyFont.ttf') format("truetype");
}

@media print {  

}
```